# Add new data center to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have the following datacenter-aware configuration:

1. Primary Datacenter: 3 node cluster, RF=3
2. Data size is more than 100GB per node

I would lite to add new data center (Secondary Datacenter: 3 node cluster, RF=3)

I know how do that.

But the problem is: How sync data from primary to secondary quickly?

I tried "nodetool repair" (with various keys) and "nodetool rebuild" but it takes much time near 10 hours.

I used cassandra 2.1.15 version

Answer (score 1):

nodetool rebuild is usually the fastest way to sync new nodes.

To speed it up you could try a couple things:

If you have a lot of network bandwidth between the data centers, try increasing the cassandra.yaml parameter inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec. This defaults to 200 Mbs, so you could try a higher value.

You could also use a smaller replication factor than 3 in the new data center, for example start with 1 to get it up and running as quickly as possible, then later alter the keyspace to a higher value and use repair to create the extra replicas.